# What is the the sum of orders of all elements of $S_n$?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

What is the the sum of orders of all elements of $S_n$?

It is quite easy to calculate this value for small $n$-s:

For $S_1$ it is $1$, as it is trivial. For $S_2$ it is $3$ (as $S_2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$). For $S_3$ it is $13$ as it has $1$ element of order $1$, $3$ elements of order $2$ and $2$ elements of order $3$. For $S_4$ it is $73$ as it has $1$ element of order $1$, $6$ elements of order $2$, $8$ elements of order $3$ and $9$ elements of order $4$. For $S_5$ it is $501$ as it has $1$ element of order $1$, $10$ elements of order $2$, $20$ elements of order $3$, $45$ elements of order $4$, $24$ elements of order $5$ and $20$ elements of order $6$.

However, I do not know, how to find this value in general.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, that list matches [A000262](https://oeis.org/A000262).

Comment: The [OEIS sequence A060014](https://oeis.org/A060014) "Sum of orders of all permutations of n letters" is what you want. It begins: $1,1,3,13,67,471,3271,...$

Comment: Since $S_n$ is a set of all bijections from ${{1,2,... ,n}}$ to itself, the result follows. Right @lulu ??

Comment: It is well-known that the behaviour of the maximum order in $S_n$ is deeply related with the distribution of primes and RH. Your sum can be expressed in a convoluted way through generating functions and Ramanujan sums, but I am afraid there is no simple algorithm fulfilling your task, nor a simple study of the asymptotic behaviour of such sum.

Comment: A very late comment but [this paper](http://emis.ams.org/journals/EJC/Volume_5/PDF/v5i1r41.pdf) provides some potentially helpful asymptotics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to “The average order of a permutation” by Richard Stong, the sum of the orders of all elements of $S_n$ has the following asymptotic:

$$n!e^{C\sqrt{\frac{n}{\log(n)}} + O\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}\log(\log(n))}{\log(n)}\right)}$$

where $C \approx 2.99047$ is a constant.